# Eclipse RCP: Disabled windows Icons in the Toolbar

Tags: java, eclipse, icons, toolbar

I tried to use my own disabled 24*24 icons in a toolbar of an eclipse app.

The scaling of the enabled icon is fine, only the disabled icon is scaled to 16*16 standard size. I tried different Images with different sizes but as soon as its larger than 16*16 it is scaled.

This problem only occurs, if on a windows machine on an apple pc it works as intended.

Has anyone an idea how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, the first icon of the toolbar had to have the same-sized disabled image in it.